# Python module not being loaded at QGIS 2.1x startup

Tags: qgis, python, installation, windows-10

I run a university module which gets students to install and use QGIS2.18 to learn about GIS. One particular student - screenshot below - downloads and installs the .exe file but the python module does not load on startup, denying her access to python plugins. The Plugins menu isn't even completed when the program is fully installed using the default settings.

80 other students have installed it with absolutely no problems.

So what's the problem here?

[image: screenshot from Windows 10 installation]